# Material design TextInputLayot, как сделать обводку(рамку) вокруг поля?

Tags: android, material-design, textinputlayout

В Материал дизайне есть описания отображение EditText [Ссылка на описание](https://material.io/components/text-fields/android#using-text-fields).
Есть два типа отображеня Filled и Outline(на моем рисунке 1 и 2 соответсвенно)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто нибудь знает как в режиме Filled сделать обводку не снизу, а полную, что-то типа рамки, как на рисунке 2.
Я пробовал решение как тут:[ccылка на найденное решение](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1187), но оне не сработало.

Подскажите пожалуйста какие есть варианты решения? Что получилось вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: то есть вам нужно сделать закрашенную рамку, или текст внутри без разницы?

Comment: Бордюр во круг рамки, как на рисунке справа>

Answer (score 0):

Добавить в xml поле для ввода:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/outlined_text_input_layout"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:placeholderText="Placeholder Text"
        android:hint="OutlinedBox">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/outlined_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

то что вам нужно находится здесь:

```
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
```

итог:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот есть хорошая [статья](https://medium.com/omisoft/textinputlayout-styling-8b36a5e0d73c).

Comment: Спасибо, но это не совсем нужно, вы добавили рамку и сразуже текст уехал на верх. А мне нужно, чтоб он оставался там же как и намоем рисунке 1.

Comment: там можно добавить hint, но визуально это будет не очень красиво

Comment: @SergeyApril, обновил ответ, то что вам нужно я так понимаю?

Comment: Навашей картинке есть надпись "OutlineBox" - вот она нужна внутри рамке, как при использовании FilledBox, но если использовать FilledBox, то рамки не будет, а тольок подчеркивание. Я прикрепил к исходной теме изображение как я планирую сделать.

Comment: ну вообще-то новая картинка отличается от того что вы просили вначале

Answer (score 0):

В итоге решил сам основывась на решении которое было по [сслыке](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1187)
Пришлось еше создать кастомную вью которая основывается на TextInputLayout, повесил слушателя на изменение фокуса и все заработало. Код ниже:

```
class ButtonCustomLayout @JvmOverloads constructor(
context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null) : TextInputLayout(context, attrs) {

override fun addView(child: View, index: Int, params: ViewGroup.LayoutParams) {
    super.addView(child, index, params)

    child.setOnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus ->
        if(hasFocus){
            editText?.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.text_input_white_background_focused)
        }
        else editText?.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.text_input_white_background_normal)
    }

    (child as? EditText)?.doAfterTextChanged {
        if (isCounterEnabled) {
            if (it != null && it.length > counterMaxLength) {
                editText?.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.text_input_white_background_error)
            } else {
                editText?.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.text_input_white_background_normal)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

}